# Ninject Conditional Self bind to change scope (For Task-scheduler) not working properly?

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control, ninject.web.mvc, ninject-extensions

Within MVC Web Application DbContext binding work properly with `InRequestScope()`

```
 kernel.Bind<DbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
 kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork<DbContext>>().To<UnitOfWork<DbContext>>();
```

But from a **Task Scheduler** call `DbContext` in `InRequestScope()` unable to update Db Table (**without any error**), until I change Binding to `InSingletonScope()` OR `InThreadScope()`

**Question:** So is their any way change scope to `InSingletonScope()` / `InThreadScope()` for a Task Scheduler Call. **?**

// For **Task Scheduler** Call, I tried bellow bind, but not working properly

```
kernel.Bind<DbContext>().ToSelf()
.When(request => request.Target.Type.Namespace.StartsWith("NameSpace.ClassName"))
.InSingletonScope();
```

** And probably I miss some thing. Need help.

**Code Snippet Updated**

```
#region Commented Code

public EmailTask() : this
 ( DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMessageManager>(),
 , DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUnitOfWork<DbContext>>()) { }

#endregion



public EmailTask(IMessageManager messageManager, IUnitOfWork<DbContext> unitOfWork)
{
            this._messageManager = messageManager;
            this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            ProcessEmail();

}

public class NonRequestScopedParameter : IParameter { ... }

public void ProcessEmail()
{
   var temp = SomeRepository.GetAll();

   SendEmail(temp);

   temp.Date = DateTime.Now;

   SomeRepository.Update(temp);

   unitOfWork.Commit();
}  

public class ExecuteEmailTask : ITask
{
  private readonly IResolutionRoot _resolutionRoot;
  private int _maxTries = 5;

  public ExecuteEmailTask(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
  {
        _resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
  }

  public void Execute(XmlNode node)
        {
            XmlAttribute attribute1 = node.Attributes["maxTries"];
            if (attribute1 != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute1.Value))
            {
                this._maxTries = int.Parse(attribute1.Value);
            }
            /// send email messages
            var task = _resolutionRoot.Get<EmailTask>(new NonRequestScopedParameter());
        }
}
```

**In Web.Config**

```
<ScheduleTasks>
     <Thread seconds="60">
        <task name="ExecuteEmailTask" type="namespace.ExecuteEmailTask, AssemblyName" enabled="true" stopOnError="false" maxTries="5"/>
      </Thread>      
    </ScheduleTasks>
```

**In Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   /* intialize Task */
            TaskConfig.Init();

            TaskManager.Instance.Initialize(TaskConfig.ScheduleTasks);
            TaskManager.Instance.Start();
}
```

**Ninject Bind Syntax**

```
kernel.Bind<DbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope(); // Default bind

kernel.Bind<DbContext>().ToSelf()
                  .When(x => x.Parameters.OfType<NonRequestScopedParameter>().Any())
                  .InCallScope();  // For Scheduler
```

**Note:** `EmailTask` class also have `SomeReposity` as a Constructor Argument.

**Queries:-**

1. But what is the bind syntax to resolve `TaskScheduler(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)` ?
2. What is the configuration code to run `TaskScheduler` ?
3. As say to put `IFakeDbContext` directly into constructor, can this work with    `IUnitOfWork<FakeDbContext>` ?

**Problem**

Task unable to call with Overloaded Constructor , it is only able to call `TaskScheduler` default Constructor.

**Question 4:** Can any way to invoke `TaskScheduler(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)` from `TaskScheduler` default constructor ?

Sample Code Snippet to create Task & run using `System.Threading.Timer`

```
private ITask createTask()
        {
            if (this.Enabled && (this._task == null))
            {
                if (this._taskType != null)
                {
                    this._task = Activator.CreateInstance(this._taskType) as ITask;
                }
                this._enabled = this._task != null;
            }
            return this._task;
        }
```

**Question 5:** Can I resolve  `TaskScheduler(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)` here ?

**Solved**

`public ExecuteEmailTask() : 
   this(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IResolutionRoot>())`

**OR**

```
 public ExecuteEmailTask() : this(new Bootstrapper().Kernel) { }

        public ExecuteEmailTask(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
        {
            _resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
        }
```

Comment: what is the empty EmailTask constructor for? Have you tried removing it? I don't know how the web stuff is instantiating things so i don't know whether this is an issue. Could you maybe please post (upload, link) a minimal solution so i can work on the problem? No need for an actual DbContext, just some empty FakeDbContext class,...

Comment: I can see why it doesn't work. `DbContext` is injected into `IUnitOfWork`, not `EmailTask` directly. So you would have to adjust the `.When()` accordingly. But there's other methods, too. Some which are more extensible ;-) If you provide a demo-solution (as said, fake DbContext only) with the scheduler, i could have a look.

Comment: BatteryBackupUnit : empty EmailTask it is actually useful for call in order to run a Task. I Update my post. please check

Comment: OK in this case - the same `DbContext` needs to used in several instances of the Task object-graph - i would recommend an entirely different solution. But i don't know whether this is feasible with the task scheduler you're using. How is the task getting started?

Comment: BatteryBackupUnit : I update My post,  have a look. YOu can get the idea how my task scheduler work.

Comment: BatteryBackupUnit: Application Start event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58879/discussion-between-shubhajyoti-ghosh-and-batterybackupunit).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58947/discussion-between-batterybackupunit-and-shubhajyoti-ghosh).

Comment: Questions 4+5: if absolutely necessary, you can use `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IResolutionRoot>()` to get an instance of `IResolutionRoot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, you should note that `InSingletonScope()` is usually a bad idea for DbContext's/Sessions. What happens if some other service changes data in the meantime? I would recommend investigating what effects this has.

---

For the scenario you first described, a correctly formulated `.When(...)` should work.

As an alternative to the `.When(...)` binding you could also use a `.Named("FooBar")` binding.
The constructor of the scheduled task would then need to look like:

```
ctor(Named["FooBar"] DbContext dbContext);
```

However, note, that this only (easily) works in case you need to inject the `DbContext` into a single constructor. If the task features dependencies and these need the same `DbContext` instance, too, it gets a bit tricker.

Since you updated your answer and say that this is the case, i would recommend an entirely different approach: Using a request parameter as basis for the `When(...)` condition combined with `InCallScope` binding. See below for an example.

Brace yourself, this is ab it of code :) The implementation requires the ninject.extensions.NamedScope extension ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope)).
I've also used xUnit and FluentAssertions nuget packages to execute the tests.

```
public class Test
{
    // the two implementations are just for demonstration and easy verification purposes. You will only use one DbContext type.
    public interface IFakeDbContext { }
    public class RequestScopeDbContext : IFakeDbContext { }
    public class CallScopeDbContext : IFakeDbContext { }

    public class SomeTask
    {
        public IFakeDbContext FakeDbContext { get; set; }
        public Dependency1 Dependency1 { get; set; }
        public Dependency2 Dependency2 { get; set; }

        public SomeTask(IFakeDbContext fakeDbContext, Dependency1 dependency1, Dependency2 dependency2)
        {
            FakeDbContext = fakeDbContext;
            Dependency1 = dependency1;
            Dependency2 = dependency2;
        }
    }

    public class Dependency1
    {
        public IFakeDbContext FakeDbContext { get; set; }

        public Dependency1(IFakeDbContext fakeDbContext)
        {
            FakeDbContext = fakeDbContext;
        }
    }

    public class Dependency2
    {
        public IFakeDbContext FakeDbContext { get; set; }

        public Dependency2(IFakeDbContext fakeDbContext)
        {
            FakeDbContext = fakeDbContext;
        }
    }

    public class TaskScheduler
    {
        private readonly IResolutionRoot _resolutionRoot;

        public TaskScheduler(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
        {
            _resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
        }

        public SomeTask CreateScheduledTaskNow()
        {
            return _resolutionRoot.Get<SomeTask>(new NonRequestScopedParameter());
        }
    }

    public class NonRequestScopedParameter : Ninject.Parameters.IParameter
    {
        public bool Equals(IParameter other)
        {
            if (other == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return other is NonRequestScopedParameter;
        }

        public object GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("this parameter does not provide a value");
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return typeof(NonRequestScopedParameter).Name; }
        }

        // this is very important
        public bool ShouldInherit
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void FactMethodName()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        // this is the default binding
        kernel.Bind<IFakeDbContext>().To<RequestScopeDbContext>();

        // this binding is _only_ used when the request contains a NonRequestScopedParameter
        // in call scope means, that all objects built in the a single request get the same instance
        kernel.Bind<IFakeDbContext>().To<CallScopeDbContext>()
            .When(x => x.Parameters.OfType<NonRequestScopedParameter>().Any())
            .InCallScope();

        // let's try it out!
        var task = kernel.Get<SomeTask>(new NonRequestScopedParameter());

        // verify that the correct binding was used
        task.FakeDbContext.Should().BeOfType<CallScopeDbContext>();

        // verify that all children of the task get injected the same task instance
        task.FakeDbContext.Should()
            .Be(task.Dependency1.FakeDbContext)
            .And.Be(task.Dependency2.FakeDbContext);
    } 
}
```

Since, as you say, the task scheduler does not make use of the IoC to create the task, it only supports a parameterless constructor. In that case you can make use `DependencyResolver.Current` (however, note that i'm in no way an expert on asp.net /MVC so i'm not making any claims that this is thread safe or working 100% reliably):

```
public class TaskExecutor : ITask
{
    public TaskExecutor()
        : this(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IResolutionRoot>())
    {}

    internal TaskExecutor(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        IFooTask actualTask = this.resolution.Get<IFooTask>(new NonRequestScopedParameter());
        actualTask.Execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes `.Named()` is a good approach, I also think about that. But `.InCallScope()` how it is work with  scheduler tasks, that need to be check. I also update my post..

Comment: BatteryBackupUnit: I Updated my code , need your suggestion.

Comment: When I put `ParentRequest` . Task not executing.

Comment: Hi, got your concept `Ninject.Parameters.IParameter` To force to load IFakeDbContext in to `InCallScope()`. I update my post

Comment: BatteryBackupUnit : `kernel.Bind<IResolutionRoot>().ToConstant(kernel);` it is trow error say more than one binding. I thik it is not required.

Comment: BatteryBackupUnit: OK. Ultimately I Solved it. I update my Post. Thanks for your help