# Ninject scoping for DBContext used in Quartz.Net job

Tags: ninject, dbcontext, quartz.net

What's the best scoping to use for a DbContext implementation that gets instantiated via Ninject dependency resolver during execution of a Quartz.Net job implementation? If I used thread scope, will the same instance of DbContext get served if the same thread in Quartz's thread pool is used to execute the job multiple times?

I would like a scope that means I get one (and only one) new instance of the DbContext each time the job is fired.

Comment: Can you confirm if the accepted solution has worked well? I'm looking into doing something similar

Comment: Yes it's certainly a vast improvement over what I had before. Initially I was just using RequestScope for everything, but that was producing a new DBContent every time it had to be injected into any dependency required by the Quartz job implementation. The only downside now is, I get a single DBContext instance when the Quartz Job implementation is instantiated, but if I ever call DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<T>() within the job's implementation code, ninject will create another new instance of DBContext for the service instance returned (if that service also depends on it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, i would advise against using `InThreadScope`. When a thread-pool thread is used, there will be leakage.

Furthermore, there's nothing built-in into ninject like a "QuartzScope", so you'll have to create your own solution. let's start with the instantiation of the job. That's covered by [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810793/how-to-inject-quartzs-job-with-ninject) and, more extensively, by [the source code of this nuget package](https://github.com/dtinteractive/Ninject.Extensions.Quartz/blob/master/Source/Ninject.Extensions.Quartz/NinjectJobFactory.cs).

Now one possible solution is to extend the JobFactory to manage the creation of the `DbContext` and inject it into the job and all its dependencies (as an inherited `ConstructorArgument` parameter). However, that has two drawbacks: Always creates a `DBContext` (whether the job needs it or not), and you need to track `DBContext` instances so you can `.Dispose()` of them in the `IJobFactory.ReturnJob(IJob)` method (p.ex. by a `Dictionary<IJob, DBContext` or the likes).

The much easier way is to use `.InCallScope` (included in [Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope)) for the `DbContext` binding. This will create one `DbContext` instance per `kernel.Get<FooJob>()`.

If you need to have different scopes for your `DbContext` - depending on where you use them, p.Ex. inside a Job and inside your ASP.NET MVC stuff, you might want to look at [Ninject Conditional Self bind to change scope (For Task-scheduler) not working properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167439/ninject-conditional-self-bind-to-change-scope-for-task-scheduler-not-working-p/25174916#25174916)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, there isn't a .InCallScope() method. I have .InThreadScope, .InRequestScope and .InTransientScope. Or, I have to do it manually with .InScope - but this is where I need the help!

Comment: Also, do I have to worry about manually disposing of the DbContext at the end of the job?

Comment: I've just discovered that .InCallScope() comes with the Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope Nuget package - for the benefit of future readers

Comment: sorry for leaving that out. I've edited the answer to include that information.

Comment: Seems to work great, thanks. I use InCallScope when instantiating my DbContext in a Quartz job, and InRequestScope otherwise. I use the When() method in the binding to test for HttpContext.Current, to tell if I'm in a Quartz worker thread or an HTTP Request worker thread

Comment: Using `HttpContext.Current` to determine which scope to use is pretty neat.